# что не так с кодом? джун

Tags: python

задача:Написать программу на Python, которая получает на вход натуральное число. Если это число кратно 3 необходимо вычислить частное от деления числа на 3. Если нет, вычислить остаток от деления на 3. Результат вывести на экран.
при введении 10 (не кратного 3-м числа) на выводе почему-то 1. такой-же ответ и в других вводных данных.
вопрос: что не так с этим кодом?

```
if x % 3 == 0:
    r = x // 3
else:
    r1 = x%3
    r2 = x/3
print(r1, r2)
```

Comment: Ну, остаток от деления 10 на 3 действительно 1. А не так с этим кодом многое. Например, он даст ошибку при вводе числа, кратного 3, потому что те переменные, которые вы печатаете всегда, в этом случае будут не определены.

Comment: Вычисляете одно, печатаете другое.

Comment: А требуется вообще третье.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
print((x // 3) if x % 3 == 0 else (x % 3))
```